# ios app engine endpoints paging

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I'm trying to figure out how to use Google Cloud Endpoints with paging. I am only getting back 10 results. I have set the property shouldFetchNextItems to YES. Also my query object does not have a nextToken or maxResults property. There is a GTLQueryCollectionProtocol with pageToken but I don't see where it is used.

```
static GTLServiceOwnit *service = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    service = [[GTLServiceOwnit alloc] init];
    service.retryEnabled = YES;
    service.shouldFetchNextPages = YES;
});

NSError *error;

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];

GTLQueryOwnit *query = [GTLQueryOwnit queryForBrandList];

[service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLOwnitBrandCollection *object, NSError *clouderror) {
   NSLog(@"counts: %d", [[object items] count]);
   ...
```

Edit:
Here is my backend in python:

```
class Brand(EndpointsModel):
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

@Brand.query_method(path='brand',
                    http_method='GET',
                    name='brand.list')
def brand_list(self, query):
    """Exposes an API endpoint to query for brands for the current user"""
    return query.order(Brand.name)
```

Thanks,

Comment: What does your backend look like? Is it Python or Java? Why should your query object have a `nextToken` or `maxResults` property?

Comment: @bossylobster I have updated my post with the backend code. I was going by the example here: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction#Result_Pages where GTLQueryTasks has a pageToken and maxResults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [paging](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/examples/paging.html) sample from the documentation.

In order for the paging parameters to be included in your API, you'll need to explicitly include them in your method:

```
@Brand.query_method(query_fields=('limit', 'pageToken'),
                    path='brand',
                    http_method='GET',
                    name='brand.list')
def brand_list(self, query):
    """Exposes an API endpoint to query for brands for the current user"""
    return query.order(Brand.name)
```

The default value of the query limit is `10`. You can change it but you should set a reasonable `limit`. It is the [`limit_default`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/blob/511c8ca87d7548b90e9966495e9ebffd5eecab6e/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py#L1343) field in `query_method`.

Comment: shouldn't the default return all the items in the Brand "table"?

Comment: Which default? Which table?

Comment: In my brand table, I have about 20 rows. When I run executeQuery on service, I should get all 20. Currently, it is paging by default and sending only the first 10.